# Suggestions for transferring int value from Service to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I have a Service that is started from a `pendingIntent`.

This service gives either a 1 or 2 int (there's a notification that contains a button, that once pressed returns 1 then 2 over and over.) Need to transfer this int to my `mainActivity` to then say (in my `mainActivity`)- `if (ServiceClass.getNum ==1)` then `mToggle.setChecked(true) else (false)`.

I heard a bunch of different suggestions on how to do this. Some of those suggestions include Binding to the activity, using a Local Broadcast receiver? Also my `mToggle` button needs to still be able to change states even if the Activity is in the background or closed.

Any suggestions on the best course of action is appreciated.

Comment: The best solution is to use Bound service.

Comment: Have you tried storing the value inside SharedPreferences? You could use a while loop to check every few seconds if the value stored inside has changed and do something if it has. I am not sure what exactly you need but it would be easy to implement and easy to test if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communicating between Android activity and service we can use broadcast receiver.
you can see this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Comment: Even if the activity is closed?